# What is the 1.12 equivalent of /execute if score?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, I want a command to execute when a score is changed.

For example, I have a scoreholder named `cameraactive` on an objective named `Debug`. I want a command to run when this score becomes 1.

I know that Minecraft Java 1.13+ has this command:

```
execute if score Cameraactive Debug matches 1 run say hi
```

Is there a way to mimic this in 1.12.2? I'm using several mods that don't support 1.13 and above and I don't have the option to upgrade versions.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to 1.13+'s `/execute if score` is the command `/scoreboard players test`:

```
scoreboard players test <scoreholder> <objective> <min> <max>
```

For example, with scoreholder `$debug.camera_active` and objective `main`, the command is:

```
scoreboard players test $debug.camera_active 1 1
```

Then you would follow with a chain command block, set to conditional mode, that runs whatever comes next.